# No more posts, but I will update content. Can I target SEO traffic for that type of site?

Tags: seo, google, google-search

I will have a plan to create a website with just 15 page.

All pages have 1000+ words and **I will update all pages in almost every month**.

Can I target SEO traffic for that type of site? Or I must create new pages?

Comment: Actually some has followed this path and created an amazing resource. For example backlinko.com has ~35 articles (4000-5000 words) and he keeps updating them and doing pretty well in serps. But his articles are pure gold and have tons of value for users. It's important to note that he do not rely only on Google traffic but his main strength is outreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite what so many SEOs tell you, search is not about keywords. Search engines do not match keywords directly and have not for a very long time. It is all about semantics (linguistics).

You have several issues.

1] Not enough content to attract search users. The more content you have, the more potential you will have to attract users. Think about it, the more stores you have the more customers you can potentially attract. Starbucks is far more successful than a single coffee shop. The same applies for content pages. The more content you have, the more likely someone will find your content.

2] Satisfying a user. Users often want to learn as much as they can. The more opportunity you provide to learn new things, the more users will stick around and read more content. Remember that your content must benefit someone else first and not you directly and exclusively or it will not perform as it should.

3] Do not create a site for search. The web is about what people want and not what machines want. Your content *must* be user centric or you will not be able to attract users. Search engines are just one channel through which users find your site but not the only one. If you rely upon search only, you will never succeed like you should. It is people that make a site successful.

4] Link opportunity. Just a few pages will not generally attract links. As well, if the page is a moving target subject wise, any link you attract can lose significant value if you are not careful.

5] If pages are constantly changing significantly and focusing on keywords, you run the risk that search engines will think you are a spam site and seriously downgrade your pages and your site.

Answer (score -1):

Yeh, You can target traffic by updating your content regularly. But I think we should create new content sometimes for attracting our visitors. Visitors like to see new content.

We can create content in various ways. Web content can also be called in different ways or names. For example, web page create, content writing, article writing, blog writing, guest blogger, guest writing, ghost writing, product description writing, facebook post create, youtube video production, news report, press release etc.

Comment: Please do not sneak links to your site into your answer